# Is there a way to insert a formatted calculation into Excel 2010 without using an image?

Tags: formatting, microsoft-excel-2010

I am maintaining a list of database column names, notes, and their calculations in an Excel 2010 spreadsheet. The calculations are included so as to document how to derive the values for the various columns and not for calculations within the spreadsheet.

I have been entering the calculations into the cells simply as unformatted text like so:

> 100 - ((FiscalYearRegionConsumption - BaselineRegionConsumption) / (GoalRegionConsumption - BaselineRegionConsumption))  * 100

However, for long and/or complex calculations this could become rather unreadable. To improve readability and comprehension I would like to "pretty" print the calculation in an Excel cell. This would result in formatting that would look something like this:

[image: Pretty printed calculation]

The only solution I have come up with is to:

1. Write the calculation in another application such as Word
2. Take a screenshot of said calculation
3. Past the screenshot into Excel

The primary concern with this approach is maintenance. Should the calculation change or need correction I have to update two different sources of information.

Is there a better way included a formatted calculation into an Excel cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a way to do exactly what I need.

1. On the `Insert` tab click the `Equation` button
2. Enter your equation into the new `Equation Text Box`
3. Select the `Equation Text Box` if it is not currently selected
4. On the `Equation Tools | Design` tab unselect `Normal Text` if it is selected
5. On the `Equation Tools | Design` tab select `Professional`
6. Right click on the `Equation Text Box` and choose `Format Text Effects...`
7. Check `Resize shape to fit text` if it is not checked
8. Uncheck `Wrap text in shape` if it is checked
9. Click `Close`
10. Align the `Equation Text Box` with the desired cell
11. Resize the cell's row and column heights as necessary to contain the `Equation Text Box`

*If your Equation Text Box does not move automatically when new columns or rows are inserted before or above its cell then you need to set additional properties.*

1. Right click on the `Equation Text Box` and choose `Size and Properties...`
2. Select `Properies`
3. Check `Move but don't size with cells`
4. Click `Close`